# Declaring (OR) Creating instance variables inside method

Tags: junit

With my experience in using easymock and powermock with Junit for the past few months, I see that when instance variables are declared and instantiated in method level scope, we need to resort to powermock framework to get it mocked.  So, can I safely assume that it is not a good programming practice to have instance variables created inside a method. Would appreciate your valuable inputs in this regard.
Thanks
Venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing the problem that Dependency Injection tries to resolve.

If I have a class Pizza which looks like this:

```
class Pizza {
    private Sauce sauce;        // instance variable
    private Cheese cheese;      // instance variable
    public Pizza() {
        sauce = new TomatoSauce();     // instantiate instance variable in constructor
        cheese = new BlueCheese();     // ... or in a method
    }
    // ...other stuff
}
```

(where `Sauce` and `Cheese` are interfaces that `TomatoSauce` and `BlueCheese` implement)

then you are correct, this is hard to unit-test without mocking. But **worse**, your Pizza class is tightly-couped to the concrete implementations `BlueCheese` and `TomatoSauce` making it hard to modify at a later date.

If you *inject* the values for the instance variables, not only do you remove the need for the mocking, your code becomes less tightly coupled. For example;

```
class Pizza {
    private Sauce sauce;        
    private Cheese cheese;      
    public Pizza(Sauce sauce, Cheese cheese) {
        this.sauce = sauce;
        this.cheese = cheese;     
    }
    // ...other stuff
}
```

One; this removes the need to mock the `Sauce` and `Cheese` variables, it also means your `Pizza` class is not tightly coupled to concrete implementations of `Sauce` and `Cheese` anymore. You can change the implementation very easily now.

For this reason, setting instance variables as in the first example is not regarded as good practice

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200709/dependency-injection-unit-testing.html

Comment: That makes sense.  But my question is having those variables sauce and cheese declared inside method scope and instantiating them.  Wanted to know if that is a right practice.  Here I have some legacy applications for which we need to do mocking, and we are having the aforementioned issue and we had to resort to using powermock for handling such scenarios.  Let me know your comments.